# Get SELECT COUNT asynchronously continuously

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables to display a grid which uses webapi to retrieve it's data. The webapi uses linq to query a mssql database and it neatly uses filtering, sorting and skip/take to assemble it's query on a well-indexed table containing about a million records (and growing). A common scenario.

And it performs really well. The browser has to wait about 50 ms for the response (while paginating for example) to return.

However, after I took a look with a profiling tool I noticed about 25 ms to be used just selecting the total rowcount of the table. Which I want to know because I want the datatable to display something like: "displaying row 1 to 10 of 45.000 filtered out of 1.000.000" needing the total count.

I don't actually need to know the precise total count (it's just informative) every trip from the server so I perhaps could keep the value server side and refresh it every second in a different task without it interfering with the data retrieval of datatables. I would just return the 'close enough' value of the total row count.

Is there a solid mechanism for that? I've tried to put the total rowcount in a static used by multiple users during multiple callbacks and every time it was requested a async task was fired to refresh it.

That feels icky however, sharing the static and having a different thread update it doesn't feel all that stable to me. I've looked at SqlDependency to push the recordcount every time it changes from my data to my domain model but that doesn't seem to support SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM TABLE scenarios.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What about using a [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) entry with absolute expiration?

Comment: Sure, better than static in a web scenario. I agree, but how to update that in a stable way.

Comment: What do you mean by "stable"? One option for updating would be to add it with a `CacheItemPolicy` that includes a `RemovedCallback` that would make the call to get the count again.

Comment: Will setting the absolute expiration of about 1 second work well? I would need the latest value to be always available even when it's underway to refresh it. When I act on removecallback the value is already gone I'd say. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, just the first thing that came into my head, perhaps not applicable for your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks for giving a thought anyway Sven.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the system tables if possible.  You could ping this every minute and stick it in the cache.  This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/07/15/sql-server-how-to-quickly-retrieve-accurate-row-count-for-table.aspx) has two that it claims are sufficient options:

```
--The way the SQL management studio counts rows (look at table properties, storage
--, row count).  Very fast, but still an approximate number of rows.
SELECT CAST(p.rows AS float)
FROM sys.tables AS tbl
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS idx ON idx.object_id = tbl.object_id and idx.index_id < 2
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.object_id=CAST(tbl.object_id AS int)
AND p.index_id=idx.index_id
WHERE ((tbl.name=N'Transactions'
AND SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)='dbo'))
```

or

```
--Quick (although not as fast as method 2) operation and equally important, reliable.
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('Transactions')   
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1);
```

Comment: That's a very interesting article. I will definitely give those a try. The downside seems however that I would need a drastic deviation from my relatively clean and simple code first model to incorporating a query to a system table. Still, I am going to consider it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered taking the count when a query is performed and then echoing the value out to your clients via SignalR?

Basically, when the LINQ call returns get a .Count() and hand off the value to a background thread to let SignalR notify the clients of the update, at the same time you return the data to the requesting client.

SignalR will activate a javascript function in all of the client pages, where you can then take the passed in value and display it somewhere on the page.

http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: I haven't considered that actually. It's an interesting take and it could work since all the users of the web application are looking at the same table with the same total record count. I could combine this having the first value on page load, just stick it in my razor. After which I update it using signalr. Interesting. Thx. I'll let you know if I try it out.

Comment: I use this technique right now to actually populate table data in some scenarios for my users.  When the data updates, I take one query of it and then signalR the entire result to the client.  1 hit on the DB and everyone gets the update.

Comment: Sounds neat, I could only use it for the total count however. Users have complex client-side filters in their browsers. While they are looking at the same table, they're certainly not looking at the same result set. I haven't really done anything useful with signalr however, so that might be a fun thing to look at. I'd still need a server-side timer of some sorts to get the latest totalcount. And using a threaded loop in MVC seems ugly.